# k nearest neighbour with count limit

Tags: qgis, clustering, nearest-neighbor

I have a set a points, and I want to create 10 clusters.

I used attribute based clustering plugin, which worked well for creating the clusters, but the points count isn't perfect, some clusters have two times more points than others.The points are close to each other, but clustering groups the closest points without taking into account the total number of points.

So I was wondering if QGIS has a feature to cluster points and make points count not necessarly equal but at least don't have a big differences.

Hierarchical clustering seems to be an option, but i can't find any implementation of it in QGIS.

Comment: Why do you want your clusters to have similar numbers? Surely the attributes define cluster membership and if you have more points with the same attributes in close proximity to each other you'll have different sized clusters.

Comment: the points represent visits, each points has a different sales volume, and sales volume has to be balanced between clusters, having the same number of points in every cluster is a starting point to get that

Comment: Wow. Okay. This is more a statistical question than a strict GIS question now. The volume of sales appears to be you're key focus? I'd suggest weighting the points by volume...or statistically clustering the points  and then geographically grouping them.