# Perform cluster with point limit?

Tags: qgis, clustering

I have a layer with about 250 points and I need to group them into groups of 30 points. How could I perform this operation in QGIS?

I researched on plugins and clustering techniques and the most common ones (k-means, hierarchical, etc.) do not present limitations to the size of the cluster, only to the radius of the cluster. I need to create cluster that upon reaching a certain size, 30, in this case, add no more points.
I did not find any plugins or metrics that explained how to do this.

To facilitate the understanding of my need, I would like to clarify that I work in a company that intends to send buses to look for its employees. However, you want to group your 250 employees into groups of 30, which is the ability of the buses in specific places, for the buses to go to the meeting place and get them all at once. For this, we want to group the employees in a group of 30 people according to the spatial location of their residence.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230906/k-nearest-neighbour-with-count-limit

Comment: Hello. First of all, thank you for the receptivity. I'll edit the question by matching it to the page.